# headsepline over whole width without moving \ohead

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I'm trying to make it so the headsepline and footepline are spanning over the whole width of the page but the header and footer contents should not move to the side.

My current approach looks like this but it gives me the wrong result

```
\documentclass[
oneside,
parskip=half-                               
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}                   
\pagestyle{scrheadings}         

\ohead{Sample Text}
\KOMAoptions{%
    headsepline=1.5pt,                          
    footsepline=1.5pt}                          
\KOMAoptions{%                                
    headwidth=\pdfpagewidth,%
    footwidth=\pdfpagewidth,%
    }
    
         % second line in header    ----------------------------------------------
\DeclareNewLayer[                           
clone=scrheadings.head.below.line,          % clone this layer
addvoffset=2pt,                             % shift it down
addhoffset=-4pt,                            % shift it left so its centered
contents={\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{cyan}} \KOMAoptions{headsepline=.5pt}  % change the line color and width 
    \GetLayerContents{scrheadings.head.below.line}},                               % use the same code as headsepline
]{scrheadings.head.below.secondline}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.secondline}   % add the layer to the page style

        % second line in footer ----------------------------------------------
\DeclareNewLayer[                           
clone=scrheadings.foot.above.line,          % clone this layer
addvoffset=2pt,                             % shift it down
addhoffset=-4pt,                            % shift it left so its centered
contents={\addtokomafont{footsepline}{\color{cyan}} \KOMAoptions{footsepline=.5pt}  % change the line color and width 
    \GetLayerContents{scrheadings.foot.above.line}},                               % use the same code as headsepline
]{scrheadings.foot.above.secondline}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.foot.above.secondline}   % add the layer to the page style


\begin{document}
This is not important
\end{document}
```

[image: example picture]

As you can see the content of the header is cut off on the edge of the page. Using \vspace couldn't solve my problem and I didn't find any other solution through searching.

Comment: I don't understand, where you want the text "Sample Text". BTW: I don't think, that the text is cut off. It is simply right aligned to the right paper edge. Do you want it aligned to the text area instead of the page? If so, you should not use `headwidth=\pdfpagewidth`. BTW: `headwidth=paper` or `headwidth=page` would be better to set the head width to the paper width. See Table 5.3 of the user manual. To setup the length/width of the line only see option `headsepline` (which you are using more than once).

Comment: Yes i want the "Sample Text" right end to be aligned with the right end of the text with the headsepline going over the whole width of the page.
Which user manual are you referring to here?

Comment: The KOMA-Script user manual, either the [German](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-de.pdf) or the [English](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) one. Both should also be available on your computer. If the text in the head should not span the whole page width but only the width of the text area, you should not use option `headwidth` (because the wanted width is already the default), but use the second value of option `headsepline` to change the length of the separation line, e.g., `headsepline=.4pt:\paperwidth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i got it working now with the following code:

```
\KOMAoptions{%
     clines,
     headsepline=1.5pt:page,
     footsepline=1.5pt:page}
```

Note that the option `clines` is important to center the headsepline horizontally. Other options are `ilines` and `olines` for inner or outer aligning respectively.

The option `headwidth=page` is not necessary since it gives the same results as `headwidth=\pdfpagewidth`.

[image: This is how it looks now]